# Omit double cloning value passed to function

Tags: clone, rust

I am writing a file watcher in Rust and I've encountered a problem with double cloning `INotify` to use it in `spawn`ed scope:

```
fn watch_file(watcher: INotify, path: &String) {
    let mut watcher = watcher.clone();
    let path = Path::new(path);
    let pusher = RedisPusher::new("redis://127.0.0.1/0", "arkona").unwrap();

    info!("Watching `{}`", path.as_str().unwrap());

    spawn(move || {
        let _ = watcher.watch(path, |_, file| {
            info!("Change in `{}`", file.path().as_str().unwrap());
            file.read_to_string().map(|content| pusher.push(content)).ok();
        });
    });
}

fn main() {
    let args = os::args();
    let watcher = INotify::init().unwrap();

    for path in args.tail().iter() {
        watch_file(watcher.clone(), path);
    }
}
```

I am still learning Rust and I cannot find any way to pass mutable watcher as value to this method. Is it the only (and idiomatic) way or is there any possibility to make it happen at most once?

Comment: Just don't clone in `watch_file`, move the parameter into the closure. What's the problem with that?

Comment: NO question now. I just cannot find the proper place for `mut`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a side note, if you take ownership of a parameter (i.e. the parameter is not a reference), you don't *have* to declare the mutability in the function signature:

```
fn add_thing(things: Vec<uint>) -> Vec<uint> {
    let mut things = things; // We own this, so we can make it mutable
    things.push(1);
    things
}

fn main() {
    let things = vec![3, 2];
    let changed = add_thing(things);
    println!("{}", changed);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just solved that by @delnan suggestion:

```
fn watch_file(mut watcher: INotify, path: &String)
```